# VC++ Building directshow baseclasses

Tags: c++, makefile, directx, platform-sdk

I am a newbie to DirectX SDK, Platfrom SDK and DirectShow. I downloaded latest Platform SDK and DirectX SDK August'09. I tried to build sample project in folder:

```
Microsoft Platform SDK\Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\Capture\PlayCap\
```

And had following building errors:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'D:\Program Files\
Microsoft Platform SDK\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\
WIN2000_DEBUG\strmbasd.lib'
```

As far, as I understand, I need to build all sources in "Microsoft Platform SDK\Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\BaseClasses\" directory to get necessary lib.
I tried nmake in that dir and got following:

```
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\
BaseClasses\ctlutil.h(278) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.
```

Here is code on that lines:

```
278: STDMETHODIMP
279: CMediaEvent::NonDelegatingQueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
```

What I do wrong? Just can't believe, that using Microsoft's libraries must be so hard.

Comment: The base classes should have a solution you can open in Visual C++. Do you have that installed?

Comment: Here: http://powerrender.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1821

Comment: I have vs 2005, but don't have solution (makefile instead it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has renamed Platfrom SDK to Windows SDK. The lastest Windows SDK is [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=71DEB800-C591-4F97-A900-BEA146E4FAE1&displaylang=en).

Windows SDK for Windows 7 has Visual Studio <strike>2008</strike> 2005 project files for all DirectShow projects.

Comment: I just had another look, the project files are for Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 1):

On my Xp64 box, I managed to get the DirectShow baseclasses libs built in order to run the amcap sample.  I have the June 2010 Microsoft DirectX SDK installed as well as the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (7.1) with all the C/C++ compilers.

First, we have to compile the DirectShow baseclasses :

open a regular old cmd.exe

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses
```

If you're getting an error about not have **VCBuild.exe** installed, it's because the
 sln and various project files (eg: C/C++ **vcproj**) are ancient, the next command will
 upgrade them nicely, changing old stanky **vcproj** files into new crappy **vcxproj** files
VCUpgrade is here on my machine :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vcupgrade.exe
```

Note that even after trying the various combinations of params to **vcupgrade**,
building the sln with **msbuild** is a no-go (docs be danged), so I had to directly
compile the project I left the batch file var named SLN anyway because I'm a real revolutionary

```
VCUpgrade -nologo -overwrite baseclasses.vcproj
```

This makes it a touch easier to compile different configurations

```
set SLN="baseclasses.vcxproj"
```

Note that the baseclasses **Release** build makes **strmbase.lib**
 and                      **Debug**         makes **strmbasd.lib**
amcap needs the **Release** build tho amcap's build can be debug

A) Compile **Release Win32** (== x86)

Using the MsSdk's **SetEnv.Cmd** lets you avoid all that **vsvars32.bat** quagmire as well
as the 8 million different cmd shells that have been specially designed to be one
or two fatal flaws away from actually working while relying upon an eplipsy-inducing web of
batch files to do they thing (hey! maybe the two are related!?)

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /release /x86 /xp
```

I've not had any luck using the 64-bit version of **MSBuild** (maybe targets?),
but x86 **MSBuild** has been working no problem

```
"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" %SLN% /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32
```

B) Compile **Release X64**

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /release /x64 /2003

"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" %SLN% /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=X64
```

Second, we can now compile both versions of **amcap**

open a regular old **cmd.exe**

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\capture\amcap
```

**VCUpgrade** the **vcproj** to a **vcxproj**

```
VCUpgrade -nologo -overwrite amcap.vcproj

set SLN="amcap.vcxproj"
```

A) Compile **Debug Win32** (== x86)

Set compiler,lib,include,... paths and then compile

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /debug /x86 /xp

"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" %SLN% /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=Win32
```

B) Compile **Debug X64**

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /debug /x64 /2003

"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" %SLN% /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=X64
```

I used **SysInternals** **Process Explorer** to verify that each exe was actually 32-bit and 64-bit respectively.  It seems inexplicable that most developers I've worked with don't even know about **Process Explorer** -- I'm in that thing all day.  And yes, that is what she said.

Comment: You 40-something guy!   :)

Answer (score 0):

For me this error meant "open C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\baseclasses.sln" (in my case, in visual studio express 2010) it asks to convert it, do so, then build both "release" and "debug."

Then in your own project, under project settings for your project

example: add
`G:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses`
to beginning of “VC++ directories” include path, and `G:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\debug` to your lib path (anywhere in that).

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407279(v=vs.85).aspx